# inconsistency in data file (xslx) for keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, psychopy

I am trying to make an experiment in PsychoPy 1.81.00 in BUILDER view where 15 conditions (picked up from an XSLX file) repeat once each randomly. The user has to give 2 responses (through 2 keyboard components each running simultaneously for the same duration).

1. Press or don't press spacebar
2. Press right or left arrow key

These responses are recorded in an XSLX file.

The key_raw are recorded correctly (as per what user presses) but the corr_raw are wrong (although key_raw and correct response matches, corr_raw is 0 for all the conditions).

I am unable to identify what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Do you really have two keyboard components running simultaneously as you describe? That would likely lead to conflicts, as there is only one keyboard to monitor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve the issue.It was a naming conflict. The variable name for storing keys was used elsewhere in program and thus was getting overwritten. I changed the names and everything worked perfectly fine.